# Which is the best field type to store pdf files, docx, jpg, and dxf files to database in bytes

Tags: c#, mysql

i just wanted to know which is the best field type to upload and store **pdf files, docx, jpg, and dxf files** to database in bytes. because i tires varchar its giving an error called insufficient space to store. 
Could you please tell. I wanted to store large number of files more than 30,000. each file is having 1-10MB in size. So which one is good?

Also i have a basic question if i use MYSQL server to store all the data's in my database. Is this data is being copied to some other place. Or while uploading data to the DB its converted as bytes[] and stored in DB.

Comment: Another option to consider is saving the file then storing the file location in the DB. Then your C# app would load the file from the location.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MS SQL server, then the Filestream datatype is best for the file sizes you describe. If Filestream is not an option, definitely consider using varbinary(MAX).

EDIT: I just noticed that you are asking about MySQL. In MySQL you need to use the [BLOB datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html). To answer your question about MySQL, as with any other SQL database, everything are stored in bytes somewhere eventually. With MySQL, this place is the file that contains the data and is usually stored locally, on the server.

Comment: For dxf files BLOB datatype or varbinary(MAX) is the best.

Comment: i don't have BLOB datatype in the field.. I have varbinary max. But the problem is, if i use varbinary and i drag the grid view to the form. I see something like X for that column field. i cannot uplaod any document to that field then.. Any solutions..